# jQuery If then with two conditions?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to run an action if two specific elements both have the class "valid". In this case I want the  fadein action preformed if both the element #fname and #lname have the class "valid"

```
  $('.step3 :button').click(function(){
  if ($('#fname').hasClass('valid')), ($('#lname').hasClass('valid')), {      

  $('.step4').fadeIn();
      } else {
    alert("Please Complete All Fields");
     }
});
```

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the logical and `&&` to specify both conditions must be truthy:

```
if ($('#fname').hasClass('valid') && $('#lname').hasClass('valid')) {
    // code here executes if both objects have the 'valid' class
}
```

You really ought to have a good Javascript reference for basic language features like this.  There are many online.  Here's [one on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Comment: You can combine as many conditions as you want with various logical operators between and can even use additional parens to group conditions.  So, yes it works with 3 conditions or 100 conditions.